# Blackberry: protecting ported Android app from unauthorised copying

Tags: android, blackberry

I ported my Android app to Blackberry. It was really easy and fast. It works OK with Blackberry 10 and Blackberry PlayBook emulators. The "only" **remaining thing to do is to find a replacement for Google Licensing Server, in other words get a protection against unlicensed duplication**, that would be fair for the user, viz. the user should be able to use the app after transferring it to a new device.

Two "safe" approaches with Blackberry, I can think of are: PIN (in can be made identical to previous one), or Blackberry ID (i.e. Blackberry login).  So far I can't find a way to retrieve either of those. The Blackberry device API (net.rim.device.api) library used for retrieving PIN appears to be incompatible with Android. As about Blackberry PIN, I tried Android AccountManager class: it always returns same address: blackberry@rim.net, even though my Blackberry PIN is registered with the device.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you planning to distribute your application?  If you are planning to do it via BlackBerry World, then AFAIK, there is no way for a user to make a copy of your application, so you don't need this protection.  You will only need license protection if you are planning to allow users to side load the application.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. If this is the case, why Blackberry World allows to provide license key (Pool Key, Static Key, etc) ?

Comment: These license models have been used for years with BlackBerry OS applications, which are not subject to this level of security - in other words, it is possible to copy an application off a BlackBerry OS device.  I suggest you confirm my thoughts by asking the question on the official BlackBerry World forum here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-World-Development/bd-p/appworld_dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution: [Blackberry Payment Service](https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberryworld/payment/). It can be accessed from Android app using Google Billing SDK, as explained [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/apisupport_inapp_payments_support.html).  I guess, it can be used for checking not only in-app payments (*virtual goods* in Blackberry terminology), but also the whole application (similarly to Google Licensing Server) through its SKU. Otherwise, you can just add a virtual good and test its purchase.